# What is the best way to call an onClick function?

Tags: jquery, function, onclick, selector

I have created this function:

```
function go_to($valor) {
    var tamano = $valor.offset().top;
    tamano = tamano - 50;
            $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: tamano
            }, 2000);
        };
```

And I'm calling it like this from my menu:

```
<ul class="right">
                <li><a onclick="go_to($('#section01'));">Section 01</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="go_to($('#section02'));">Section 02</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="go_to($('#section03'));">Section 03</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="go_to($('#section04'));">Section 04</a></li>
            </ul>
```

My question: are there are other better ways of calling the `onclick` functions and send their section ID?

Comment: What do you mean by better?

Comment: as a matter of personal choice I always separates event handling from elements like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qd93x/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answers everyone.

As I posted, I usually call my functions with "onClick" html code online, but it seems a bit outdated. I will try all your answers to see which one works better in different devices and browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should not use intrusive JS but declare event handlers outside the markup:

**JS**

```
$('.right a').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this.href).offset().top - 50
  }, 2000);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="right">
    <li><a href="#section01'">Section 01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section02'">Section 02</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section03'">Section 03</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section04'">Section 04</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<ul class="right">
   <li><a class="link">Section 01</a></li>
   <li><a class="link">Section 02</a></li>
</ul>
$(".link").click(function(){
   var tamano = $(this).offset().top;
   tamano = tamano - 50;
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: tamano
        }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your HTML to:

```
<ul class="right">
    <li><a href="#section01">Section 01</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Your JS should be

```
$('.right').on('click','a',function(e){

  e.preventDefault(); // prevent default click behavior

  var target = $(this).attr('href'); //assign value of a's 'href' to 'target'

  go_to(target); // use your function

});
```

Your function should be:

```
function go_to(valor) {
    var tamano = $(valor).offset().top;
    tamano = tamano - 50;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: tamano
    }, 2000);
};
```